# Swap and reverse two methods

Tags: java, methods, reverse, swap

Create a class named Flip with two methods:

```
public float[] swap(float[] pair)
```

The swap method should take an array containing two floats.  It should return an array containing the same two numbers in swapped position.  For example, if I call your method swap like this:

```
float[] x = { 3.14, 2.71 }

float[] y = swap(x);

Ln.p(y[0] + “, “ + y[1]);
```

my method calling your swap method should print out `2.71, 3.14`.

```
public double[] reverse(double[] reverse, int length)
```

The reverse method should take an array containing any number of doubles (specified in length).  It should return an array containing all of those numbers in reverse order.  You do not have to use a for loop, but that is the easiest way to write this method.  If I call your method reverse like this:

```
double[] a = { 0.33, 0.66, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 }

double[] b = reverse(a, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Ln.p(b[i] + “ “);
```

my method calling your reverse method should print out `0.75 0.5 0.25 0.66 0.33`.

---So I have the first one for the float, but am looking for a starting point or direction on the second part.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Flip 
enter code here{


public float[] swap(float[] pair) 
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;

    int xi = Float.floatToIntBits(x);
    int yi = Float.floatToIntBits(y);
    xi = yi - xi;
    yi = yi - xi;
    xi = xi + yi;
    x = Float.intBitsToFloat(xi);
    y = Float.intBitsToFloat(yi);

    System.out.printf("My method calling your swap method is...." +x,y); 

    return null;
}

public double[] reverse(double[] reverse, int lenght)
{
    double[] a = { 0.33, 0.66, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 };

    double[] b = reverse(a, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Ln.p(b[i] + “ “);

    return reverse;

}

}
```

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that you shouldn't call reverse **while in** reverse.

Answer (score 0):

To swap to elemtens in an array of size 2 I'd do:

```
float[] array = {2.7, 3.2};
float x = array[1];
array[1] = array[0];
array[0] = x;
```

Also don't forget to actually return your swapped array!

To reverse a whole List or Array I would recommend using the reverse() Method in Collection. Take a look at
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_reverse.htm

If you want to do that with your own method, try copying the values from the input array in an output array with the same size, but in reverse:

```
float[] input = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
float[] out = new float[input.length];
for(int i=0;i<input.length; i++) {
  out[i]=input[input.length-i-1];
}
```